# How to show confirmation box on delete in grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

When click on delete link, confirmation box has not been opened so please suggest me how to open confirmation box on delete?

On View page

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<QuoteModel>(Model.Quotes.Data)
                    .Name("quote-grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(x => x.QuoteSentence);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Status)
                            .Width(100)
                       .Template(x => x.Status.ToString().ToLower())
                            .Centered();
                            columns.Bound(x => x.IsDelete)
                            .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text, "Edit", new { id = x.Id }))
                            .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
                            .Width(50)
                            .Centered()
                            .HeaderTemplate(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text)
                            .Filterable(false);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                             .Width(50)
                             .Centered()
                             .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text, "Delete", new { id = x.Id }))
                             .ClientTemplate("<a href='' onclick='Deletemsg(#=Id#);return false;' id='#=Id#'>@T('Admin.Common.Delete')</a>")
                             .HeaderTemplate(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text);

                    })
              .Pageable(settings => settings.Total(Model.Quotes.Total).PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("QuoteList", "Quote")
             )
                                            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                                            .EnableCustomBinding(true))
```

Java Script for delete

```
 function Deletemsg(id) {
        alert("hiiii");
        var ID = id;
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 170,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                '@T("Admin.Delete.Conform")': function () {
                    var id = ID;
                    window.location.href = 'Delete/' + id;
                },
                '@T("Admin.Delete.No")': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Dialog Box for confirmatio box

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title='@T("admin.DeleteBox.Title")' style="display:none">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>"@T("Admin.Delete.Conform.Message") @T("Admin.Configuration.Catalog")"</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text, "Delete", new { id = x.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure?');" }))
```